# Density of Function Spaces in the Context of Uniform vs. Pointwise Convergence

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $A,B$ and $C$ are Banach spaces such that $A \subset B \subset C$. There are a few different wasy
that I am aware of to think about the set $A$ being dense in $B$. One is to say that $A$ is dense
in $B$ if and only if $\bar{A} = B$ where $\bar{A}$ denotes the set $A$ together will all of
its accumulation points which, alternately, can be considered as the intersection of all closed sets
containing $A$. An equivalent way to say that $A$ is dense in $B$ is to say that for every point of
$B$ one can find a sequence in $A$ that converges to $B$. I particularly like this characterization
because it avoids having to distinguish between 'closed in B' versus 'closed in C'.

Now lets suppose that the spaces involved are Banach function spaces with the supremum norm. My question
regards how the distinction between pointwise convergence and uniform convergence comes into play
when considering whether $A$ is dense in $B$. For example, suppose one has a sequence of functions $(f_n)$
in $A$ that converges uniformly to a function $f$ in $B$. Considerations of whether $A$ is dense
in $B$ in this case don't depend upon the point at which the function is evaluated so the same definitinition
of density as applied to general Banach spaces as indicated above can be applied in this instance. 
What can be said though if the convergence of $(f_n)$ to $f$ is not uniform?

My thoughts are that the property of $A$ being dense in $B$ would vary from point to point and thus would
not be well-defined. Is this the right way to think about this?

Comment: Why is $C$ mentioned?

Comment: Because in the first paragraph I was making a distinction between closed in $B$ versus closed in $C$ (in which I made a typo so the closed in $C$ part wasn't there)

Comment: If you are considering $A$ and $B$ with the restricted norm from $C$, then because $B$ is a Banach space, it is closed in $C$.  That implies that a subset of $B$ is closed in $B$ if and only if it is closed in $C$.  Similarly, $A$ is closed, so it is dense in $B$ if and only if $A=B$.  Did you mean to say that they are complete, or do you really want to consider normed (not necessarily complete) spaces?

Comment: @JonasMeyer I am only considering complete (Banach) spaces; I did not consider that a vector subspace of a Banach space is complete itself if and only if it is closed, but that makes sense. What I'm really trying to understand though is whether the concept of density has any meaning in relation to pointwise convergence. I think perhaps my first paragraph detracts from this intent..